# Converting repr to Hex

Tags: python

I received the following string.How can it be converted to hex `value='(\xd2M\x00\x18\x00\x18\x80\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xd2\xe0\xd2.\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x18\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f0\xfe/\x010\xff/\x000\xff/\x000\xff/\xff/\xff/\xff/\xff/\x000\xff/\xff/\xff/\x000\x000\xff/\x000\x000\x000\xff/\xff/\x000\x000\xff/\x000\xad\xff\x0c\x00\xdd\xff\xc2\xff\xd3\xff\xde\xff\xe9\xff\xca\xff\xd8\xff\xe6\xff\xb5\xff\xb2\xff\xe6\xff\x92\xff\xd0\xff\xa0\xff\xbd\xff\xb4\xff\x82\xff\x90\xfff\xff\xe1\xff\x9f\xff\x94\xff\xd4\xff\xa4\xff\xbb\xff\xe8\xff\x00\x00\x02\x00\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\x97\xff\xd0\xff\xb7\xff~\xffG\xff\xa1\xff\xa1\xff\xcd\xab\x00\x00A\n\x00\x00'`

Comment: That's not a hex string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a hex string. You are confusing the Python `repr()` output for a bytestring, which aims to make debugging easier, with the contents.

Each `\xhh` is a standard Python string literal escape sequence, and displaying the string like this makes it trivial to copy and paste into another Python session to reproduce the exact same value.

You don't need to hex decode this at all.

An actual hex string consists *only* of the digits `0` through to `9`, and the letters `a` through to `f` (upper or lowercase). Your value, converted to hex, looks like this:

```
>>> value='(\xd2M\x00\x18\x00\x18\x80\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xe0\xd2\xe0\xd2.\xd2\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x18\x00&\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f0\xfe/\x010\xff/\x000\xff/\x000\xff/\xff/\xff/\xff/\xff/\x000\xff/\xff/\xff/\x000\x000\xff/\x000\x000\x000\xff/\xff/\x000\x000\xff/\x000\xad\xff\x0c\x00\xdd\xff\xc2\xff\xd3\xff\xde\xff\xe9\xff\xca\xff\xd8\xff\xe6\xff\xb5\xff\xb2\xff\xe6\xff\x92\xff\xd0\xff\xa0\xff\xbd\xff\xb4\xff\x82\xff\x90\xfff\xff\xe1\xff\x9f\xff\x94\xff\xd4\xff\xa4\xff\xbb\xff\xe8\xff\x00\x00\x02\x00\xff\x7f\xff\x7f\x97\xff\xd0\xff\xb7\xff~\xffG\xff\xa1\xff\xa1\xff\xcd\xab\x00\x00A\n\x00\x00'
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(value)
'28d24d00180018800080000000000000e0d2e0d22ed20000000000000a00180026000000000000000f30fe2f0130ff2f0030ff2f0030ff2fff2fff2fff2fff2f0030ff2fff2fff2f00300030ff2f003000300030ff2fff2f00300030ff2f0030adff0c00ddffc2ffd3ffdeffe9ffcaffd8ffe6ffb5ffb2ffe6ff92ffd0ffa0ffbdffb4ff82ff90ff66ffe1ff9fff94ffd4ffa4ffbbffe8ff00000200ff7fff7f97ffd0ffb7ff7eff47ffa1ffa1ffcdab0000410a0000'
```